# Por qué no me aparece el studio Bot en mi Android studio?

Tags: android, studio

Estoy tratando de utilizar el studio Bot, pero simplemente no aparece en las opciones, ya instalé la versión iguana más reciente y simplemente no aparece las opciones

Comment: Bienvenido, Podrías agregar mayor información de lo que estás realizando, por ejemplo el código, para tener una idea de lo que sucede,  ¿Revisaste el LogCat?.revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.